# Anaconda in VS2017 not seeing packages

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, numpy, package, anaconda

VS Community 2017, v 15.9.10
Anaconda 2019.03  (This is python 3.7.3)

I have a simple program, given here:

```
import numpy
import sys
print("version = " + sys.version)
print("hello, world!\n");
```

If I go into VS, Python Environments and lick "Open in Powershell" I can type "python" in that window, to get an interactive python session.  It says "Anaconda 2019.03 environment"

If I type: print(sys.version), int eh interactive console, it prints:

> version = 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit
>   (AMD64)]

OTOH, if I attempt run the program via right click-->"Start without Debugging", I get the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import numpy   File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py",
>   line 140, in 
>       from . import _distributor_init   File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py",
>   line 34, in 
>       from . import _mklinit ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Press any key to continue . . .

Note: only the first line is causing the error, namely "import numpy"

Also, if under Python Environments, I click on the "Open interactive window" and manually type in the command "import numpy" I get the same error.

When I look at Python Environments and check conda packages, I see all the packages I need ... numpy, many others.

Now, it didn't work in the powershell at first either, but I found some commands relevant to ExecutionPolicy to help with that.  I thought this would fix the interactive window as well, but it doesn't.

So it appears that the anaconda python listed under python environments is different that the one that it brings up with I click on the "open interactive window" icon.

Here's what the Python Environments window looks like:
[image]

Here's the interactive window when I try to import numpy
[image]

Note the example is using numpy, but this is true of other packages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, but VisualStudio 2017 insists on installing its own instance of Python, e.g. C:\Users\*you*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36.  Under this instance you will find C:\Users\*you*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs, where an entirely different set of hosed-up MKL libraries lurks.

When you use Visual Studio, it is this instance rather than Anaconda.

Use Settings | Apps & features to uninstall it.

After you do that, you're going to have to figure out how to point VS at Anaconda.  I recall there is workflow for scientific computing that will integrate Anaconda.